# what is the meaning that AMD RDNA support wave32?

Tags: amd-gpu, amd-rocm

From AMD [RDNA white paper](https://www.amd.com/system/files/documents/rdna-whitepaper.pdf), it is said

> The RDNA architecture is natively designed for a new narrower wavefront with 32 work-items,
> intuitively called wave32, that is optimized for efficient compute. Wave32 offers several
> critical advantages for compute and complements the existing graphics-focused wave64
> mode.

As we know, the size of wavefront is 64. Does wave32 mean that we can config the wavefront from 64 to 32?

Is there any coding example about wave32?

Answer (score 0):

> While the RDNA architecture is optimized for wave32, the existing
> wave64 mode can be more  effective for some applications. To handle
> wave64 instructions, the wave controller issues and executes two wave32 instructions, each operating on half of the work-items of the
> wave64  instruction. The default way to handle a wave64 instruction is
> simply to issue and execute the  upper and lower halves of each
> instruction back-to-back – conceptually slicing every instruction
> horizontally.

https://www.amd.com/system/files/documents/rdna-whitepaper.pdf

An example of application, CAS

> AMD’s FidelityFX suite includes a new approach known as Contrast
> Adaptive Sharpening (CAS)  that uses post-processing compute shaders
> to enhance image quality. CAS enhances details  at the interior of an
> object, while maintaining the smooth gradients created by the
> antialiasing as illustrated in Figure 12. It is a full-screen compute
> shader and therefore can work  with any type of anti-aliasing and is
> particularly effective when paired with temporal antialiasing.
>
> CAS is extremely fast, taking just 0.15 milliseconds for a 2560x1440
> frame, and benefits from a variety of features in the RDNA
> architecture such as packed integer  math for address calculations,
> packed fp16 math for compute, faster image loads, and wave32.